# How to reuse a language token in a custom Grammar (Raku)

Tags: raku, nqp

I want to reuse the `token parameter` from [Perl6::Grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/77defa770e13bb48c17a2ba034001453b479fdde/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L2650) in my custom slang to add a "custom-param" parameter **without cargo culting**.

What I mean:

```
my $main-grammar = $*LANG.slang_grammar('MAIN');
my $main-actions = $*LANG.slang_actions('MAIN');

role Nogil::NogilGrammar {
    token parameter { # the new one
        "custom-param" || < here the token stolen from $main-grammar.^find_method('parameter'); >
    }

my $grammar = $main-grammar.^mixin(Nogil::NogilGrammar);
my $actions = $main-actions.^mixin(Nogil::NogilActions);
$*LANG.define_slang('MAIN', $grammar, $actions);
```

Not sure it is clear: it is like calling the parent token in a token of a role. I know the role will overwrite it so I kept a backup of pristine object in `$grammar`.

Already tested:

1. Define it as a method returning the Match object of the parent but got the following error:

```
P6opaque: no such attribute '$!pos' on type NQPMatch in a Scalar when trying to get a value
```

2. Return from a Regex code interpolation

```
Attempt to return outside of immediately-enclosing Routine (i.e. `return` execution is outside the dynamic scope of the Routine where `return` was used)
```

Comment: Maybe easyer: Can I transform a `NQPMatch` object in `Match` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Intro:** After many similar errors with nqp, I figured out:

**Brief:** `nqp` + `Scalar` in error message -> replace `=` by `:=`

**Explain:**
Use the bind operator [:=](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_:=) and not assignment [=](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_=_(item_assignment)) which autobox in a Scalar hence the error message with Scalar.

**Demo:** A fully working example (use in BEGIN [phaser](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers)). Trying "my" `€` sigil and "their" (compile in the language) in case mine fails.

```
my $main-grammar = $*LANG.slang_grammar('MAIN');
my $main-actions = $*LANG.slang_actions('MAIN');

role Nogil::NogilGrammar {

    method sigil {
        # Bind
        my $sigil-they := $main-grammar.^find_method('sigil');
        my $sigil-me := self.sigil-eu;
        # Check My
        return $sigil-me if $sigil-me;
        # Return Their
        return $sigil-they(self);
    }

    token sigil-eu { '€' }
}

my $grammar = $main-grammar.^mixin(Nogil::NogilGrammar);
$*LANG.define_slang('MAIN', $grammar, $main-actions);
```

**Note1:** I removed some `say` essential for the demo. Just add `.Str` to those exoteric objects (NQPMatches).

**Note2:** If you want to create temporary variables (like `$res`), keep binding (`:=`).

Comment: Hello, I've run your code and get the error: `Dynamic variable $*LANG not found
  in block <unit> at - line 2`. Not sure what to do, thanks.

Comment: I may have forgotten to prepend `use nqp;
use QAST:from<NQP>;` The LANG dynamic variable is defined in nqp parsers.

Comment: [there](https://github.com/tinmarino/nogil/blob/master/lib/Slang/Nogil/Grammar.rakumod) is the grammar.rakumod code I ended up with